# Subquery returned more than 1 value How To Fix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing a problem. I have two tables `FreshStock` and `PurchaseInvoiceDetails`.

When a new product is received, it goes into `PurchaseInvoiceDetails` and I want it to go into the second table as well.

I have code that first checks if product is not added in the `FreshStock`, then it first adds it, but if it already have added it, then it updates it by ProductName. I get an error when updating it:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

My code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FreshStock] WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FreshStock] ([ProductCode], [ProductName], [Stock],[IsAvailable])
        SELECT [ProductCode], [ProductName], SUM([Box]), 1
        FROM [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails]
        WHERE ProductName = 'Makki Rusk'
        GROUP BY [ProductCode],[ProductName]

    RETURN
END

IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FreshStock] WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk')
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[FreshStock]
    SET [ProductCode] = (SELECT [ProductCode] 
                         FROM [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails] 
                         WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk'),
        [ProductName] = (SELECT [ProductName] 
                         FROM [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails] 
                         WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk'),
        [Stock] = (SELECT SUM([Box])  
                   FROM [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails] 
                   WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk')
     WHERE ProductName = 'Makki Rusk'
END
```

Comment: Table DLL, sample data, etc. would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to re-set the code and the name, so just set one column:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FreshStock]
SET [Stock] = (SELECT SUM([Box])
               FROM [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails]
               WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk'
              )
WHERE  ProductName = 'Makki Rusk';
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting indicates that one of the following subqueries is returning multiple rows and needs to be modified to only return a single row:

```
[ProductName] = SELECT [ProductCode] FROM [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails] WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk'
[ProductName] = (SELECT [ProductName] FROM [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails] WHERE [ProductName] = 'Makki Rusk')
```